# sql find max value of a column and select as new field

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am currently working with some ambulance data and in some scenario's multiple vehicles are dispatched to the same call. Of those dispatched sometimes they are stood down(diverted to a different call.)

The relevent fields are `incidentID, VehicleAllocationSequenceNumber snd VehicleArrivalAtSceneDateTime`.

An `incidentID` can map to multiple rows with different `VehicleAllocationSequenceNumber` and `VehicleArrivalAtSceneDateTime`.

VehicleAllocationSequenceNumber defines the order in which the vehicles arrived on the scene. `VehicleArrivalAtSceneDateTime` is either a `datetime or NULL` if the vehicle never arrived.

I want to select `distinct IncidentID's` with and condense the other columns into two new features; `Number_of_Vehicles_assigned` and `number_of_vehicles_on_scene`

I am fairly new to queries of this complexity and I am looking for a way to do this without using a cursor.

Thanks in advance

Edit:
Nevermind I nailed the query, think I'm just a bit scatter brained this morning. Here is my query for posterity's sake.

Feedback is welcome:

```
select
    IncidentID,
    max(VehicleAllocationSequenceNumber) as number_vehicles_assigned,
    count(VehicleArrivalAtSceneDateTime) as number_of_vehicles_on_scene
FROM
    [dwuserobj].[acc].[AmbulanceLinkedDatasetForModelling]
where
    IncidentID in(
        select distinct
            IncidentID
        from
            [dwuserobj].[acc].[AmbulanceLinkedDatasetForModelling]
    )
and vehicleArrivalAtSceneDateTime is not null
group by
    IncidentID;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think I've solved it in my edit

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` with a `not exists`

```
select distinct incidentID,
  case
    when not exists 
        (
        select 1 
        from AmbulanceTable t2 
        where t2.incidentID = t1.incidentID
        and t2.VehicleAllocationSequenceNumber is null
        ) then 1
    else 0 as alloc,
  case
    when not exists 
        (
        select 1 
        from AmbulanceTable t3 
        where t3.incidentID = t1.incidentID
        and t3.VehicleArrivalAtSceneDateTime is null
        ) then 1
    else 0 as onscene
from AmbulanceTable t1
```

Edit:

So no_vehicles is number of vehicles... my bad:

```
select incidentid
       count(VehicleAllocationSequenceNumber) as num_assigned,
       count(VehicleArrivalAtSceneDateTime ) as num_oncscene
from AmbulanceLinkedDatasetForModelling
group by incidentid
```

this will give you zeros if none assigned/on scene

Answer (score 0):

this should provide you with the logic you need. I made a temp table so you can see how the incidentID interacts with the  AllocationSequenceNumber and the SceneDateTime.

```
DECLARE @AmbulanceLinkedDatasetForModelling TABLE (IncidentID int, VehicleAllocationSequenceNumber int,  VehicleArrivalAtSceneDateTime datetime)
INSERT INTO  @AmbulanceLinkedDatasetForModelling
SELECT 1, 500, NULL UNION ALL  -- the vehicle never arrived
SELECT 2, 501, '2016-05-20 06:07:00.370' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 502, '2018-01-05 08:15:08.970' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 503, NULL UNION ALL -- the vehicle never arrived
SELECT 4, 504, '2017-04-11 11:22:01.360'UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 505, '2017-04-11 11:32:01.360'

SELECT 
    IncidentID, 
    number_vehicles_assigned=COUNT(DISTINCT VehicleAllocationSequenceNumber), 
    no_vehicles_on_scene=SUM(CASE WHEN VehicleArrivalAtSceneDateTime IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM 
    @AmbulanceLinkedDatasetForModelling


GROUP BY
    IncidentID
```